# Justify AlertDialog text

Tags: android, textview, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a class of a generic AlertDialog in a DialogFragment, which works fine. I use it for example to pop-up an "About" dialog.

Problem is the text in the dialog is not justified so it doesn't look very nice.
Is there a way I can justify the text? Meaning, align it to both right and left sides?

This is the relevant function in my code:

```
@Override
public AlertDialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Resources res = getActivity().getResources();
    String title = getArguments().getString("title");
    String message = getArguments().getString("message");
    String yesButton = getArguments().getString("yes_button");
    String noButton = getArguments().getString("no_button");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert);
    if (!noButton.equals(""))
        builder.setNegativeButton(noButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                mCancel.run();
            }
        });
    builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.my_launcher)
            .setTitle(title.equals("") ? res.getString(R.string.app_name) : title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(yesButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mConfirm.run();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    // text MATCH_PARENT
    TextView messageView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams messageViewLL = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) messageView.getLayoutParams();
    messageViewLL.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    // If only positive button, center it.
    if (noButton.equals("")) {
        Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams positiveButtonLL = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) positiveButton.getLayoutParams();
        positiveButtonLL.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean align title/message text, then instead of `.setTitle(String)` use `.setCustomTitle(View)` and instead of `.setMessage(String)` use `.setView(View)`, you can just align text or set padding:

```
    TextView titleView = new TextView(context);
    titleView.setText(title.equals("") ? res.getString(R.string.app_name) : title);
    titleView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END);

    TextView messageView = new TextView(context);
    messageView.setText(message);
    messageView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    messageView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            // your code

    builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.my_launcher)
            .setCustomTitle(titleView)
            .setView(messageView)
            .setPositiveButton(yesButton, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mConfirm.run();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, alignment is not what I'm looking for, but justify. Justify is like when both left side and right side of the text are aligned. Like you see in books or in this picture for example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLIBP.png